# Can j# be used to provide jdbc functionality to an asp.net mvc application?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, jdbc, j#

I have a service which exposes a JDBC interface ("yolus"/"ion arc" if anybody is familiar), and i'd like to be able to commincate with it from .net.

I'd rather not use an ODBC-JDBC Bridge, it's a real pain.

Is it possible to use J# for this and to integrate with or expose it to an existing .net codebase (asp.net mvc 2).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

J# is no longer supported so I would recommend you to stay away from it. Also why would a .NET application ever need *JDBC functionailty* when there's ADO.NET?

Comment: When JDBC is the only interface available? The system does not support ODBC. I'm not overly concerned with it being supported to be honest, it's not for production software.